prove this set doesn't have density
We define the natural density for a set A like this:
$$d(A)= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,n\}|}{n}$$
Consider an increasing sequence of positive integers $\{a_n\} $ that fulfils the condition
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}=1 $$
Prove that the set
$$ \qquad\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{2n},a_{2n+1})\cap \mathbb{N} $$
has the upper asymptotic density equal to $1$ and the lower asymptotic desity equal to $0$
I thought about finding two subsequences of this sequence:
$$ \dfrac{|A\cap \{1,2,...,n\}|}{n}$$ such that the limit of one of them is $1$ and the limit of the other is $0$. For example, I thought about writing $n=a_{2n+1}$ and $n=a_{2n}$ and trying to find the limits, but I couldn't find them. I also remembered that I had  studied a special case of this set and the result of these limits was 1/3 and 2/3.
How can I prove this theorem? Especially since here the calculation of the upper limit and the lower limit by the general definition is very difficult!

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $n_0$ large enough such that
$$ \forall ~ n \geq n_0, \quad a_n \geq (a_1 + ... + a_n) (1 - \varepsilon) $$
so in particular
$$ \forall ~ n \geq n_0, \quad \varepsilon a_n \geq (a_1 + ... + a_{n-1}) (1 - \varepsilon) $$
Denote by
$$ d_n(A) = \frac{|A \cap \{ 1, ..., n \}|}{n} $$
Consider now the subsequence $(d_{a_{2n+1}})_n$. You have for $n \geq n_0$ :
$$d_{a_{2n+1}} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{a_{2j+1} - a_{2j}}{a_{2n+1}} \geq 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{a_{2j}}{a_{2n+1}} \geq 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} $$
But you can choose $\varepsilon > 0$ as small as you wish, thus this means that the limsup is at least $1$, so it is $1$.
Considering the subsequence $(d_{a_{2n}})_n$ gives you that the liminf is $0$.
The main trick here is that, in order to prove that some limsup or liminf is something, you can choose a subsequence to get an appropriate bound (and here the other bound is automatic).

what did you mean with $ a_{2j+1} - a_{2j}$ in that sum above? is it the number of natrual numbers in interval $ (a_{2j}, a_{2j+1}) $ ? I think the number of natrual numbers in this interval is $a_{2j+1} - a_{2j} +1 $. is this false?

in my first comment I have written  that the number of natural numbers in that interval false. I think it has to be $ a_{2j+1}-a_{2j} -1 $

You can prove $a_n \to \infty$ so an additional constant $1$ or $-1$ will not change the result.

thank you very much
